# Regex with multiplier for single character inside character set

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need a Regex for validating a phone number. White space allowed (but only one at a time).

**OK:** `+45 1234 1234`

**NOT OK:** `+45  1234 1234`

**OK:** `0045 54 45 45 45`

**NOT OK:** `0045 54  45 45   45`

I tried `/^[+]?[0-9\s-]*$/` but it's not working as it allows for multiple white space.

Comment: Try `/^\+?[0-9]+(?:[\s-][0-9]+)*$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS6puS/1)

Comment: Why did you remove your regex attempt? Please rollback.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew. can you explain why your suggestion works? When testing I notice that when adding a single white space, the regex is invalid until i add a numeric char after it. I suspect that is part of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^[+]?[0-9\s-]*$` regex matches a string that starts with an optional plus (`[+]?`) and then has an unlimited amount (0 or more) of digits, whitespaces or hyphens, thus, it even matches `"+      --- "` string:

[image]

You need to use

```
/^\+?[0-9]+(?:[\s-][0-9]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS6puS/1) and the [regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5C%2B%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5B%5Cs-%5D%5B0-9%5D%2B)*%24):

[image]

Mind to keep `-` at the end of the character class in `[\s-]` if you want to keep it unescaped, or escape the hyphen inside the character class, `[\s\-]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `\+?` - an optional `+` symbol
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[\s-][0-9]+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more repetitions of

  - `[\s-]` - a character class matching a single whitespace or `-`
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `$`  - end of string

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```js
var re = /^\+?\d+(\s\d+)*$/;
var strings = ["+45 1234 1234", "+45  1234 1234", "0045 54 45 45 45", "0045 54  45 45   45"];
strings.forEach(s => console.log(s.match(re)));
```

Comment: Your regular expression can be simplified:  ^\+?\d+(\s\d+)*$

Comment: You didnt provide a solution yet @WiktorStribiżew. Do so and I will approve